# Deserializing optional nullable fields in jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have an `Employee` class that I want to serialize like this:

```
class Employee {
  String name;
  @JsonUnwrapped
  EmployeeId id; 
  @JsonUnwrapped(prefix = "previousEmployee")
  EmployeeId previousEmployeeId;
}

final class EmployeeId{
 @JsonProperty("id")
 private final long value;

 @JsonCreator
 public EmployeeId(@JsonProperty("id") long value) {
    this.value = value;
 }
}
```

Serializing `Employee` gives the following json:

```
{
  "name":"foo",
  "id" : 123,
  "previousEmployeeid" : 456
}
```

However, the `previousEmployeeId` is optional. So if I try to deserialize this json, it puts the `id` into `previousEmployeeId` field. What am I doing wrong?

```
{
  "name":"foo",
  "id" : 123
}
```

I would want the field `previousEmployeeid` to be `null` but it is assigned a value `123`.

Comment: That's tricky. I bookmarked it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Et voilà!

```
final class EmployeeId {
    @JsonProperty("id")
    private final long value;

    @JsonCreator
    public EmployeeId(@JsonProperty("whatever") long value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

see the `whatever` as `@JsonProperty` value. You can throw in anything that **isn't** empty, but not `id`.
And btw, this must be some sort of bug.

---

Remember it can't be `null`, as the internal `value` is of a primitive type. And the wrapper object won't be null anyway.

---

Using `JsonCreator` with `JsonUnwrapped` you cannot have a `null` `EmployeeId`

[image]

---

I always test my code. It works.

[image]

Comment: Changing it to whatever, it gets passed value=0 now. I want `previousEmployeeId` to be null, but it now has the value EmployeeId(0).

Comment: @user3111525 you cannot have a null EmployeeId. For that you need a custom JsonNodeDeserializer

Comment: @user3111525 that's the contract of JsonCreator. Jackson gives you the potentially null value as constructor parameter

Comment: @user3111525, `id` type is `long`. If you need `null` you need to change type to `Long`. You can not assign `null` to primitive type.

Comment: @MichałZiober Yes. But he wants a null wrapper object (EmployeeId), but that's not possible with JsonCreator + JsonUnwrapped

Comment: @user3111525 I posted an example

Comment: But deserializing this does not work:
{
  "name":"foo",
  "id" : 123,
  "previousEmployeeid" : 456
}

I mean, the previousEmployeeid is 0.

Comment: @user3111525 post the updated code, you must be doing something wrong here.